# Group with Full Control sees all web parts...can we stop that?

Tags: list-view, audience-targeting, list-view-web-part, custom-permission-level

I have a page with multiple web parts based on a single list.  Each web part is set to it's corresponding Views of the list.
Each view has an associated Group (Contribute permission) assigned to it.  So the Target Audience setting is working wonderfully are the Group can only view their the assigned web part.
The only issue I am having is One of my Group has Full Control and they can see ALL the individual web parts.  I just want this group to only see the AllItems List View Web Part.
Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, for my situation, I just added a new Group with Contribute permissions and I got the effect I wanted...they can see the AllItems view and not all the views.  I guess the Full Control bypass everything (list settings, Target Audience, etc.) thus anyone with Full Control will see all the Views.